# Visual viewport controls

Tags: python, 3d-view, add-on

I've been using Blender since 2007 and before I've used (in that order) MiniCAD, Strata Studio Pro, Alias Wavefront and Cinema 4D. I love blender and I could never go back to my previous love Cinema 4D because I think Blender is simply better once you get the hang of it.

Now I am starting a 3D project with other people and most of them are using Cinema 4D. We decided to use Blender and I am introducing them to the workflow. A general issue with the interface is viewport navigation. Most of them are used to point and click so I am thinking about writing a plugin for Blender.

Basically what I want to achieve is this:

[image: blender viewport navigation]

I have a lot of experience with Ruby and JavaScript programming and I will be able to get into Python really quickly. I only need a few pointers to get me started. So here are a few questions:

- how can I add such a hanging tab to the 3d viewport
- how can I activate pan/zoom/rotate of the viewport when the mouse button is pressed
- is there an existing addon to build on?

Comment: There is a fly mode available using Shift+F shortcut, not the best solution, but if you have some spare money I would suggest to get Space Navigator 3D mouse from 3DConnexion.

Comment: That's not what I am after really. As you should have read, I need a point/click/drag solution.

Comment: I know you are asking for a specific solution, but if you are looking to streamline the process consider a pie-menu specifically for those functions. **pros** 1) Less travel time for the mouse,  2) you don't have to move the mouse into the 20*20px box at the top of the window to start a behaviour.

Comment: There are viewport navigation add-ons here's a list of useful threads: [how-can-i-navigate-the-viewport-using-python](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/674/how-can-i-navigate-the-viewport-using-python),  [how-can-i-control-the-viewport-without-a-mouse](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1511/how-can-i-control-the-viewport-without-a-mouse/1543#1543)

Answer (score 1):

1. [Download this addon](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4U5LpqB83HWeFFyeW9welVjY1E/view)
2. Blender > File > User Preferences (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>) >

   - Add-ons Tab > Install from file... > Choose the downloaded file > Save user setting
   - Input Tab 
     [image: User Settings Input tab]

     > Save user settings > Close User Preferences

Now in the viewport you can use

- touchpad > drag = rotate
- touchpad > <kbd>Alt</kbd>+drag = moving
- touchpad > <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+drag = zoom

In the Node Editor you can use

- touchpad > <kbd>Alt</kbd>+drag = moving
- touchpad > <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+drag = zoom