# Can I match the viewport direction to gravity with python?

Tags: python, physics

In order to simulate a specific production process in Blender I need to ensure that the scene's gravity "down" is aligned with the viewport's angle.

In other words in this case:

[image]

"Down" should be along the x-axis, like this:

[image]

I know I can get the view matrix and decompose it like this:

```
t, r, s =  bpy.context.space_data.region_3d.view_matrix.decompose()
```

and I can get/set the scene's gravity like with

```
bpy.context.scene.gravity
```

How do I combine the two so that things always fall "from" the viewpoint and "towards" the point being looked at?

Comment: It sounds like you want top view.  Numpad 7 gives you top view and numpad 5 toggles between orthographic and perspective.   If you do want to manipulate the viewport viewpoint see [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/678/42221)

Comment: @MartyFouts - thanks, but actually, no: I want to simulate the process of glueing of a patch onto a curvy surface withminimal distortion: this process would not always happen along the Z axis

Comment: Did you see the answer I posted the pointer to?  It shows how to do the combining.  Isn't that what you want?

Comment: Yes, I did. Maybe it’s me but I don’t get the connection - apart from getting the rotation matrix. Should I brush up on matrices and vectors instead of asking questions?

Comment: I can't know what do and don't already know, so I have to ask when things I thought might help didn't so I can figure out how to help.  I also have to ask questions to make sure I understand what you really want.

Comment: Sure! That’s the way I read it, and I appreciate you doing that. Sorry if it came across otherwise. And my question was without sarcasm - it could be that working harder on understanding matrices would get me there

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131500/discussion-between-simone-and-marty-fouts).